# World Bank and OECD statistics unmatch tax revenue as % of GDP

Tags: gdp, statistics, public-economics, taxation, data

I have been looking for statistics on tax revenue to GDP ratio of different countries. I've found it on World Bank website.

https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/GC.TAX.TOTL.GD.ZS?view=chart

which claims that it is 11.5% for Germany (2018) for example.
Then I have seen this page from OECD website

https://www.oecd.org/tax/revenue-statistics-germany.pdf

which claims that it is 38.5% for Germany (2018).
How come there's such a huge difference between these two sources? Is there something I'm getting wrong here? How can there be 27% difference, OECD number is more than 3 times world bank number! Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: 11.5% is implausibly low and so may be measuring something else.  The [German government](https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/EN/Standardartikel/Topics/Taxation/Articles/2019-08-22-taxation-international.html) says "In 2017, Germany’s tax ratio – i.e. the ratio of taxes and social security contributions to gross domestic product (GDP) – stood at 37.5%."  It may be a "social security" issue (though excluding that the figure would be 23.3%), or something else

Comment: The only thing that makes sense is that the 11% figure is the federal (central) government, while the 38% is “general government” - all levels of government. For apples-to-apples comparisons, you want general government, since different countries have different splits. You would need to dig and find the series definition; I could not find it on the web page linked to.